# Traigo los datos de una API en Angular y creo que los guardo bien sin embargo no se me renderiza esta información en el Componente html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, datos

Muy buenas compañeros, estoy tratando de renderizar en el componente html cierta información de esta API https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com y esto es lo que guarda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado una interfaz para tipar esta información y almacenarla esta datá en un array para luego utilizar ese array y renderizar los datos en el componente html pero esto no ocurre. Nos se si alguno me pudiera ayudar diciendome que estoy haciendo mal, agradezco mucho cualquier sugerencia. Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
//Modelo interfaz de los datos
export interface Jugadores{
  first_name: string;
  h_in: number;
  h_meters: number;
  last_name: string;
}
export class AppComponent  {

//Variable que almacena los datos de la Api:
  datos: Jugadores[]=[]

  constructor (private http: HttpClient){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getAllPlayers()
  }
  //Metodo que trae los datos:
  getAllPlayers(){
    return this.http.get<Jugadores[]>('https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com')
    .subscribe( data => {
      this.datos= data
    });
  }
```

}

Esto es lo que tengo en mi componente html:

```
<div *ngFor="let dato of datos">
  <p>{{ dato }}</p>
</div>
```

Realmente no me sale nada en el navegador, sin embargo la petición es aceptada y los datos se traen al subscribirse

Comment: Es porque los datos están dentro de una propiedad llamada `values`.

Comment: Lo intente pero ahora me marca error y no me deja almacenar los valores en la variable datos. Este es el error que me aparece: "Al tipo "() => IterableIterator<Jugadores>" le faltan las propiedades siguientes del tipo "Jugadores[]": pop, push, concat, join y 25 más."

Answer (score 1):

Como te ha dicho *@Lobos* en un comentario los datos los tienes dentro de la propiedad `values` de la respuesta. Por tanto tienes que modificar dos cosas en tu código:

1.- Tienes que cambiar el tipo del genérico del http.get para reflejar el formato correcto de la respuesta.

```
this.http.get<{ values: Jugadores[] }>(...)
```

*Si lo prefieres puedes crear una nueva interface que refleje este formato en vez de definirla directamente.*

2.- En el subscribe tienes que asignar la propiedad `datos` a `data.values`

```
this.datos = data.values;
```

un saludo